# Choose unique stylesheet for a single page with php

Tags: php, html, css

My question is: is it possible to have different stylesheets on the same website? I’m already aware that its possible to link several stylesheets to each other but that isn’t quite what I’m looking for. My goal is to make it possible for a logged in administrator to edit a stylesheet that only affects the look of the start page.

The website uses php for connecting the pages to one another and the links to the stylesheets are located in the `header.php` document:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['stylesheet'])): ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/<?php echo $_SESSION['stylesheet']; ?>"> 

<?php else: ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/stylesheet.css" title="General stylesheet">

<?php endif; ?>
```

Would it be possible to modify this code so that an alternative stylesheet controls the look of the front page exclusively?

Comment: You can just create another stylesheet which only styles the front page, or am i misunderstanding you?

Comment: Yes there is an existing stylesheet that I would like to link to the start page exclusively. The problem is however that I don’t know how to make that stylesheet just affect the start page. The linking part is my problem :)

Comment: Do you have a way to detect what page you're on? E.g. `get_page_id()`?

Comment: Yes, the id of the page that should be affected is hem, the document starts out like this:                                 `<?php 
include("incl/config.php");
$pageId = "hem";`

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment that the start page has a variable `$pageId` with the value `hem` you can include a stylesheet exclusively to the start page by adding

```
if($pageId == "hem") {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/stylesheet/for/startpage.css">';
}
```